# Hungarian algorithm for face matching

Tags: algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I am building multiple face tracker for Android and I am using Kalman filter which apparently needs some algorithm above it to distinguish between tracked objects and currently I am interested in the Hungarian algorithm.

I do undestand how the algorithm works but I cannot figure out how to build the input matrix if I have 2D space with coordinates. So let's just say I've detected 3 people in the frame:

```
**Person1** on the coordinates [10, 20]
**Person2** on the coordinates [100, 125]
**Person3** on the coordinates [50, 200]
```

In the next frame there are still 3 persons detected on the new coordinates but now I want to know which one was **Person1**, which one was **Person2**, etc. in the previous picture.

Now I am not quite sure how to build the matrix.
The columns should be different people like this:

```
+---------+-x1--y1--x2--y2--x3--y3-+
| Person1 |                        |
| Person2 |                        |
| Person3 |                        |
+---------+------------------------+
```

And the values are the distances between current position and the last found ones?
I know it might seem stupid but I am confused.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hungarian method solves the bipartite matching problem. To my understanding, its application in motion tracking solves an assignment problem.

Suppose you have two points `A` and `B` of same type in a model; these might be geometrical points in space (or instances of other models).

Now you have two measurements (imagine positions), namely you measure `X1` and `X2` at some instant in time and `Y1` and `Y2` at some other instant in time. The problem woud now to decide whether `X1` corresponds to `Y1` and `X2` to `Y2` or the other way round.

The approach would be to have some measure on the points (imagine euclidean distance). So each interpretation would correspond to an assignment; the assignment would have a total cost induced by the measure. Using the Hungarian method, a cost-minimal assignment is chosen. The approach is justified by the argument that the cheapest assignment would be the most probable one.

Comment: Thank you, so if I put it in more simple way: my rows will be coordinates detected in the current frame, columns are coordinates from the previous frame and the values are euclidean distance between these points?

Comment: This seems to be right. To my understanding, the partitions between you would like to match (in you formulation, the rows and columns of the cost matrix) would be the persons in different frames. In your original question however, you are writing of 3 persons which constitute the rows and then 6 columns. You would rather have 3 columns.